# Take image dimensions and apply them to another image

Tags: javascript

PROBLEM: I have 2 images, one is taken from my database using `src=data:image;base64,$row[2]` and has given dimensions.

The other image is taken from an HTML element with `ID=img00` and it is a transparent image. I need the transparent image to have the same width and height of the image taken from my database.

MY GUESS: I would like to save getMeta output to 2 variables for width and height, that I would later use instead of `'200px'`.

Do you believe there's a smarter way than this code? 
Else, what would I have to do to save getMeta output and use it instead of that 200px?

```
  function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}

getMeta(
  "data:image;base64,$row[2]",
  function(width, height) { alert(width + 'px ' + height + 'px') }
);

var img00 = document.getElementById('img00');
if(img00 && img00.style) {
    img00.style.height = '200px';
    img00.style.width = '200px';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the values from inside getMeta, you are going to have to change the timing of the execution of the last block of code. Perhaps something like this?

```
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}

function sizeImg00(w,h){
    var img00 = document.getElementById('img00');
    if(img00 && img00.style) {
        img00.style.height = h + 'px';
        img00.style.width = w + 'px';
    }
}

getMeta(
    "data:image;base64,$row[2]",
    function(width, height) { 
        console.log(width + 'px ' + height + 'px');
        sizeImg00(width, height);
    }
);
```

Comment: it did work, you just inverted width "w" with height "h". Thanks!

Comment: so I did ^_^; I'll fix.